# Excel macro for copying data from a specific field in one sheet keeping only the value and adding it to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I am very limited to what I can run in the workbook, so I'm limited to macros.  I've created a form style layout in a sheet, as I can't use VB to make a userform.

I know the specific cells that I wish to copy the data from, however they are merged together and this is what seems to be causing the problem.

```
D6 (D6:F7 is merged) -> sheet1!A3
D9 (D9:F10 is merged) -> sheet1!B3
D12 (D12:F13 is merged) -> sheet1!C3
D15 (D15:F16 is merged) -> sheet1!D3
D18 (D18:F19 is merged) -> sheet1!E3
D21 (D21:L26 is merged) -> sheet1!F3
D28 (D28:F29 is merged) -> sheet1!G3
J6 (J6:L10 is merged) -> sheet1!H3
J12 (J12:L13 is merged) -> sheet1!I3
J15 (J15:L16 is merged) -> sheet1!J3
J18 (J18:L19 is merged) -> sheet1!K3
```

I already have a macro that inserts a new line on the sheet at row 3, hence why it will always be A3:K3 range.

No idea where to start, have tried recording a macro just copy pasting but it takes the size of the merged cells from the form sheet into the other sheet.

EDIT: This is what I've got so far but it just seems to put the data in the wrong places.

```
Sub AcceptedSave()
'
' Adds new line to Accepted database and saves info from form.
'
    Call AcceptedNewLine
    Sheets("Call Sheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("D6").Select ' Get Provider
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Call Sheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("J6").Select ' Get Address
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Call Sheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("J12").Select ' Get Postcode
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Call Sheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("D9").Select ' Get Contact Name
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("D3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Call Sheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("D12").Select ' Get Contact Email
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("E3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Call Sheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("D15").Select ' Get Contact Telephone
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Call Sheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("J15").Select ' Get Job Profile
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Call Sheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("J18").Select ' Get Work Type
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("H3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Call Sheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("D18").Select ' Get DBS Requirement
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("I3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Call Sheet").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("D21").Select ' Get Notes
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("L3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Range("K3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Yes"
    ActiveSheet.Range("M3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Y"
    ' Sheets("Call Sheet").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: If you use VBA why you don't get directly the value of the cell and set on the new ? Something like that: // Sheets("Accepted Providers").range("B3").value = Sheets("Call Sheet").range("B3").value // in this case you don't have prb with merged cells and the code are more lite...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on user3514930's Comment above, I have come up with the following working solution.

```
Sub AcceptedSave()
'
' Adds new line to Accepted database and saves info from form.
'
    Call AcceptedNewLine
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Range("A3").Value = Sheets("Call Sheet").Range("D6").Value ' Get Provider
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Range("B3").Value = Sheets("Call Sheet").Range("J6").Value ' Get Address
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Range("C3").Value = Sheets("Call Sheet").Range("D9").Value ' Get Postcode
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Range("D3").Value = Sheets("Call Sheet").Range("D9").Value ' Get Contact Name
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Range("E3").Value = Sheets("Call Sheet").Range("D12").Value ' Get Contact Email
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Range("F3").Value = Sheets("Call Sheet").Range("D15").Value ' Get Contact Telephone
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Range("G3").Value = Sheets("Call Sheet").Range("J15").Value ' Get Job Profile
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Range("H3").Value = Sheets("Call Sheet").Range("J18").Value ' Get Work Type
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Range("I3").Value = Sheets("Call Sheet").Range("D18").Value ' Get DBS
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Range("L3").Value = Sheets("Call Sheet").Range("D21").Value ' Get Notes
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Range("K3").Value = "Yes"
    Sheets("Accepted Providers").Range("M3").Value = "Y"

End Sub
```